# Como nosso site será graduado?

Tags: suporte, status-pronto

Desde a criação do Stack Exchange 2.0 que possibilitou a criação desse site, alguns passos foram definidos para a criação e graduação de um site na rede.

Já passamos pelas primeiras fases, definição e comprometimento. Agora vamos para a última fase antes da graduação, dividida em duas partes: *private beta* onde estamos no momento que escrevo essa pergunta e depois virá o *open beta*.

Foi dito que esse site era diferente e teria um processo incomum. Fica claro que já começamos com nome e domínio determinado, e estilo visual definitivo. Só falta completar a tradução.

Os prazos serão os mesmos? Os critérios para entrar no beta aberto e depois a graduação serão mesmos? Temos vantagens ou desvantagens em relação ao que sempre foi adotado? Ainda não podemos ir a público? O que falta?

Teremos uma conta *twitter* para divulgação das perguntas? Teremos um blog oficial específico? Newsletter oficial? E principalmente, haverá um Careers em português?

Hoje a maioria das empresas ignoram essa ferramenta do SE quando fazem recrutamento e as opções de divulgação de currículos que existem no Brasil (não sei os outros países lusófonos) são péssimas para os profissionais e eu nem chamaria de concorrentes porque trabalham de forma inversa onerando o profissional.

O que mais teremos de diferente no processo?

Comment: Realmente é importante ter um horizonte para isso. Até porque é importante ter parâmetros para saber se vale a pena investir um pouco mais de esforço ou se já estamos bem. Fiquei triste ao descobrir esses dias que após 3 anos em *open beta* o *Answers on Startups* foi encerrado por pouca atividade. Não gostaria que acontecesse o mesmo por aqui.

Comment: @utluiz *Acredito* que não corremos muito esse risco aqui, vamos ter participação no mínimo suficiente para o site ser graduado. Acho que o risco é não ter qualidade suficiente para valer o esforço. Agora está tudo ótimo, mas quando chegar o grande público, novato...

Comment: Acredito que a qualidade vem com o tempo, com a maturidade dos novatos e principalmente com uma boa orientação a esse público para que além de contribuir com suas questões eles tenham o SOpt como referência. Vai ter com certeza muita coisa improdutiva, que faz parte do processo de crescimento, tanto do site como dos membros. Creio que o foco por enquanto é a divulgação do SOpt, criar uma cultura de oferecer boas respostas com conteúdo e cordialidade. No final das contas o benefício também é nosso mesmo, não pelo peso no currículo, mas por poder contar com uma solução nas horas de dúvidas.

Comment: Fiz uma pesquisa sobre o *quando*: **1)** [What is the Stack Exchange (Staff) process of launching a site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200383/185667), **2)** [What are the success criteria for an Area 51 beta site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76392/185667) e **3)** [Can we grandfather in rep abilities as sites leave beta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67062/185667)