# Onde podemos socializar?

Tags: debate, comportamento, comunidade

Existe uma coisa que alguns usuários fazem, especialmente os novatos na plataforma, que não cabem aqui no site. É a socialização nas perguntas e respostas.

Porque não posso socializar nos posts? Onde posso então?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Quem observa tudo o que ocorre no site já deve ter notado que alguns usuários, especialmente o bfavaretto e eu editamos posts com saudações, agradecimentos e outras frases e expressões que nada acrescentam.

Como somos um site de **perguntas** e **respostas**, o importante são elas. A conversa deve ser deixada de lado. Nós retiramos rapidamente este tipo de texto para deixar claro que eles não devem ser usados, para que ninguém ache que eles são válidos.

Temos que ser objetivos, fazer perguntas ou respondendo como se estivessemos em uma prova, um exame, um teste. Não cabe conversa com quem está lendo.

E ainda tem um outro problema com a saudação quando se usa algo temporal. Em comunicação síncrona como chat, Skype, telefone, etc. saudação temporal não gera problema, mas em comunicação assíncrona como e-mail, carta, posts em fóruns, blogs, e um site de Q&A, você não sabe quando a pessoa vai ler e está desejando algo possivelmente sem sentido.

Retiramos esses textos além de retóricas como "Alguém pode me ajudar?" para deixar o post brilhando por si próprio.

Claro que alguma coisa extra pode até ficar se não comprometer o conteúdo. Mas onde podemos ser mais condescendente, é nos comentários.

**Comentários** servem principalmente para ajudar a entender o post ou o uso do site. Conversas paralelas não são boas mas não causam muito mal. É comum e aceito que se faça comentário um pouco fora do assunto direto do post. O site pode ser mais informal e um pouco divertido nos comentários. Eles não fazem parte da pergunta ou resposta, nem é indexado pelos buscadores. Não abuse, mas tenha mais liberdade nos comentários.

Outro lugar onde se aceita um comportamento mais informal, onde podemos ter opiniões, agimos diferentemente, e até socializamos um pouco é aqui **no meta**. O ponto principal do meta é discutir o nosso site, decidir o que fazer, resolver os problemas da comunidade, enfim, administrar a comunidade. Embora seja mais flexível, os posts de perguntas e respostas ainda são importantes. Os comentários são bem mais livres e frequentemente usamos eles para diversão.

Somos adultos responsáveis e não estamos trabalhando aqui. Não precisamos de regras muito rígidas se não atrapalhar o objetivo principal do site. Só não podemos atrapalhar o conteúdo ou causar confusão com os membros.

Quer mais liberdade? O [**chat**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) serve para isso. Nele temos bastante liberdade. Basicamente as regras são as mesmas de qualquer outro chat, onde o mais importante é respeitar as outras pessoas.

Mas dá para ir além e ter um ponto de encontro dos membros onde pode-se socializar mesmo?

Acabei de criar um [grupo no Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/408861909259821/) e outro no [Linkedin](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Stack-Overflow-Portugu%C3%AAs-7450344). Não esperem que eu apareça por lá, até dou a propriedade deles para quem quiser, mas são locais que podem ser usados para socializar e divulgar um pouco mais o nosso site.

Não criei *Twitter* porque não ajudam tanto nesta questão e acho (mas [não tenho certeza](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/141/como-nosso-site-sera-graduado)) que a equipe vai criar uma conta que ela controle para fazer *stream* de postagens nossas. A [conta oficial no Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackOverflowPT) foi criada pela equipe.

Então é isso, evitem prejudicar o objetivo principal do site mas tenha bom humor e divirtam-se no site também.

Comment: Realmente muita gente com qual falei tem dificuldade com este aspecto mais formal das postagens. Eu mesmo apesar de saber que se trata de um Q&A acho que um certo nível de cordialidade nunca fez mal a ninguém, pelo menos um pequeno comentário agradecendo caso a resposta tenha sido satisfatória, sinto que faltei com minha educação caso não o faça. Mas se for mal visto posso não o fazer. Ah! E se precisar de ajuda com o grupo no FB é só falar.

Comment: @ArthurdeAndrade Farei um post específico sobre agradecer sem criar ruído.