# O que fazer com o "espero ter ajudado" no final das respostas?

Tags: debate

Já vi várias respostas com a frase ["espero ter ajudado"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22espero%20ter%20ajudado%22) ao final.

Na minha opinião, isso é irrelevante, já que seria meio óbvio que a resposta dada a uma pergunta seria para ajudar - está certo que, em alguns casos, as respostas  só pra ganhar *upvotes*, mas não é o assunto a ser debatido.

Não seria melhor remover essa frase do final das respostas?

Comment: Acredito que seja o mesmo caso de saudações.

Comment: @rray se fosse *"Que a sorte seja com você"* (caso fosse uma resposta de uma pergunta PHP) eu até entenderia :p

Comment: @WallaceMaxters e teria o mesmo tratamento que as saudações também.

Comment: Ou "tenta a sorte pq o azar é certo"

Comment: @JorgeB. ok. Então temos muito trabalho pela frente. Só clicar no link do primeiro parágrafo que você vai ver que tanto de coisa tem lá...

Comment: Talvez seja apenas meu ponto de vista, mas vi muitas respostas que não tem quase explicação nenhuma (só tem código) que o cara tá colocando "espero ter ajudado" no final. Parece que a consciência pesou de não ter botado uma explicação, daí botam "espero ter ajudado"

Comment: @WallaceMaxters ["boa sorte"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22boa+sorte%22) com isso :P

Comment: Pra resolver esse problema, só com um mutirão.  Eu achei que eram apenas 50 perguntas por aí, mas pra minha surpresa: **"1,318 resultado"**

Comment: Tem como dizer isso sem ser uma coisa solta. Tem um lado que é uma questão de estilo, parecido mas um pouco diferente de saudações. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu não tenho nada contra, o mundo já é tão frio, tão impessoal, mas se a era das máquinas for invitavel, quem sou eu para evitá-la,,, Pi pi shutdown -h now,,,

Comment: @MagicHat também não vejo mal em assinaturas, o problema é que se a resposta não contem detalhes ou explicações e se foca apenas em dizer *"tente isto ... código ... espero ter ajudado"*, o que acontece na maioria das vezes. De resto se for uma resposta útil a comunidade, além do AP, a assinatura não faz bem ou mal, é apenas uma maneira de se comunicar. Vejo muitas edições para remover assinaturas, mas elas não corrigirem os reais problemas, como tags erradas, como código mal "marcado". Acho que se for para remover a assinatura ao menos as pessoas deveriam se concentrar nos outros problemas.

Comment: Nesse caso, não que um seja certo e outro esteja errado, mas seria interessante corrigir **tudo**!

Comment: Esse mutirão vai sair ou vai ficar só na pergunta? Eu já sugeri num fim de semana, mas ninguem deu resposta no chat se vai ou não participar.

Answer (score 20):

Qualquer informação irrelevante "deve" ser retirada.

Isso é praticamente uma assinatura.

Muita gente não sabe que tem uma suspensão padrão para quem faz assinaturas regularmente. Sorte ou azar que ninguém aplica.

Veja [o que diz a Central de Ajuda sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Isso já foi discutido em [Saudações e Agradecimentos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/101).

Em [Onde podemos socializar?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/587/101) fala que aqui não é rede social. Não saudamos, agradecemos, não nos dirigimos ao usuário diretamente, pelo menos em perguntas e respostas, não tem porque dizer "alguém pode me ajudar?", "obrigado pela ajuda", ou "espero ter ajudado", ou "me diga se não fui claro" porque isso é óbvio. Estamos aqui para isso.

Lembre-se que uma pergunta deve ser como se fosse uma prova. A resposta deve ser como você responderia uma prova. O avaliador que aplica a prova não fica conversando com que vai responder, quem responde não fica com conversa mole na resposta. Não tem conversa, porque aqui não é um fórum. É um site de **perguntas e respostas**.

Lembre-se que esses textos serão usados para SEO, texto que não ajuda identificar o assunto pode atrapalhar a pesquisa.

Comentários são mais liberais, eles não fazem parte do Q&A. Por outro lado usamos mais do que deveria e apagamos menos do que seria o normal. Sempre que tem um comentário significa que o site não está sendo usado da melhor forma possível. Claro que não dá pra pregar perfeição, mas no mundo perfeito não teria um comentário sequer.

Uma forma de não entulhar a página principal de edições é fazer assim que você vê a postagem com esse problema, de preferência assim que ela é postada.

Se for fazer em coisa antiga, faça bem aos poucos ou em horário de baixo movimento.

Comment: *...Lembre-se que esses textos serão usados para SEO...* eu ia citar isso na minha pergunta, mas pensei que alguém poderia considerar irrelevante.

Comment: Só não exagera nas edições, pleo menos em horário de grande movimento.

Comment: Eu já falei isso com o rray no chat. Eu vou dar uma pausa.

Comment: Acho que os melhores horários para essas edições em massa, pelo que percebi no site, É após as 19 horas durante a semana, e fim de semana.

Comment: Eu não tenho tanta certeza nesse caso, como comentei lá na pergunta. Mas se forem mesmo tentar limpar isso, não vou me opor.

Comment: Edição de resposta sobe a publicação?

Comment: @PabloAlmeida sim.

Comment: Apesar de concordar em geral que informações irrelevantes podem ser retiradas, há considerações culturais e, principalmente no caso do "espero ter ajudado", considerações sobre o *real* impacto que a edição causa na qualidade do site. A ideia por trás de evitar saudações e agradecimentos é desobstruir o caminho da informação relevante e uma frase ao final do post não está exatamente atrapalhando qualquer informação relevante de obter o destaque necessário. Tecnicamente é algo que ***pode*** ser retirado sem problemas, não significa que ***deve*** ser retirado sem ressalvas, automaticamente.

Comment: Meu ponto geral, como sempre é: **Tenham parcimônia** e pensem se essa é a melhor maneira de gastar a energia de vocês. Trazer aquela busca da pergunta de 1200 resultados pra 0 vai garantir um site melhor? Vai tornar o SOpt mais confiável? Vai garantir o crescimento sustentável do site? Garantir que a lei seja sempre seguida, nos seus mínimos detalhes, apenas por ser "a lei", pode não ser a melhor maneira de passar seu tempo aqui.

Answer (score 7):

Concordo que qualquer informação extra deve **ser removida**, no entanto estou respondendo para colocar o meu ponto de vista do que deve ser ou não prioridade.

Ao meu ver algo como *espero ter ajudado*, não é bom e nem mau, admito que sempre removo, todavia peguei várias edições aonde a postagem tinham vários problemas, mas as pessoas se focaram em remover apenas a saudação. As respostas e perguntas que notei que tiveram a saudação removida tinha problemas com:

- Marcação
- Falta de quebra de linha
- Palavras/gírias as vezes incompreensíveis.

E mesmo após a edição a pessoa que removeu a saudação não se preocupou em aproveitar para editar os demais problemas.

Nas perguntas a maior parte dos problemas são as tags mal usadas, a maioria têm edições variadas, até para corrigir marcação, mas quase ninguém se preocupa em remover ou corrigir as tags.

### Resumindo

Se for para editar, edite e melhor e tudo o que puder, definindo as principais preocupações:

1. Tags problemáticas
2. Marcação de texto
3. Gírias ou abreviações

O que **nunca** se deve fazer é mudar o código, tipo indentar ele para torná-lo legível, isto porque mexer no código pode conflitar no problema que esta sendo apresentado, a única coisa que deve-se fazer é corrigir a marcação e/ou remover ou adicionar o *Stack Snippet* quando necessário.

Pra finalizar, se a resposta está bem esclarecedora, bem marcada e descrita, remover um texto de saudação ali é quase desnecessário, o problema são as respostas com quase nenhum esclarecimento sobre o problema.

Comment: Bom, eu posso falar por mim que, a maioria das resposta que editei que tinha "espero ter ajudado", só tinha código (salvo duas, se não me engano, que o texto estava muito bem formatado).

Comment: Discordo que a edição que foi reprovou foi "absurda", ou até mesmo desnecessária. A diferença da sua pra dele foi apenas reiterar o que já tinha sido dito no título, o que não é necessariamente errado mas numa pergunta tão curta, pode parecer redundante. Também definitivamente não concordo que as **únicas** alterações que devam ser feitas num trecho de código sejam de identação. Vejo como protecionismo que faz pouco para ajudar a comunidade, em troca de uma aderência estríta demais à regras arbitrárias de "posse" sobre um conteúdo que é, essencialmente, comunitário.

Comment: @Gabe não é protecionismo, por favor entenda, o problema é evitar "problemas", simples assim: Se o cara vai e quer ajustar o codigo, muitas vezes o problema pode estar ali na identação, linguagens que aceita usar ifs, loops sem o `{}` quando usados apenas uma linha PODEM SER AFETADOS no comportamento de resposta de uma condição IF. Eu não disse para não fazer porque devemos é do "AP", é pra não fazer pra evitar dar problema. E outra eu não foquei só em uma parte, veja bem eu disse tem coisa que é "prioridade" e tem gente que gasta tempo com coisa que não deveria ser prioridade..

Comment: ... se for pra editar pra corrigir uma virgula aproveita e olha se tem mais coisas erradas. Foi isso.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não vi nenhuma mistura dentro do código. Apenas identação

Comment: @Gabe vou remover esta parte, foi realmente falta de atenção minha

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Concordo plenamente sobre "se vai editar, aproveita e edita tudo", é algo que precisamos incentivar. Mas ainda vejo o risco de causar um problema na resposta por desatenção na edição como algo bem secundário, num site repleto de programadores, onde edições são públicas e nós temos diversos mecanismos de verificações e reversões.